# Загрузить картинку из XML в PictureBox

Tags: c#, парсер

Мне необходимо загрузить из `XML` кода картинку в `PictureBox`.

```
<image>
    <title>Yahoo! Weather</title>
    <width>142</width>
    <height>18</height>
    <link>http://weather.yahoo.com</link>
    <url>http://l.yimg.com/a/i/brand/purplelogo//uh/us/news-wea.gif</url>
</image>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, как это сделать.

Comment: Проект WinForms?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Я использовал `LINQ to XML`:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

Загружаем исходный xml-файл:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\admin\Documents\test.xml");
```

Получаем данные нужного тэга (адрес картинки):

```
XElement picElement = xdoc.Root.Element("url");
```

Показываем картинку:

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = picElement.Value;
```

Это если структура xml такая:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<image>
    <title>Yahoo! Weather</title>
    <width>142</width>
    <height>18</height>
    <link>http://weather.yahoo.com</link>
    <url>file:///C:/Users/admin/Pictures/ku.jpg</url>
</image>`

Если сложнее, то читайте здесь [1](https://habrahabr.ru/post/24673/) [2](http://professorweb.ru/my/LINQ/linq_xml/level5/5_6.php)